# I want to open a file just with one click of button in java in a new window

Tags: java, applet

My file is 1.txt and I want to open it using java such that on pressing a button, that file should open up!!
Is there any command through actionlistener to open the file and patch it with the button??
This is my simple applet program in java..

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CalculatorApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {

    Button save, view;
    Label fname, lname, email, city, phno;
    TextField t, u, v, w, x;
    Label ans;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setLayout(null);

        // create label to display enter no
        fname = new Label("Enter First Name : ");
        fname.setBounds(10, 50, 100, 20);

        lname = new Label("Enter Last Name : ");
        lname.setBounds(10, 70, 100, 20);

        email = new Label("Enter Email : ");
        email.setBounds(10, 90, 80, 20);

        city = new Label("Enter City : ");
        city.setBounds(10, 110, 80, 20);

        phno = new Label("Enter Phno : ");
        phno.setBounds(10, 130, 80, 20);

        // create textbox for entering number
        t = new TextField();
        t.setBounds(120, 50, 200, 20);

        u = new TextField();
        u.setBounds(120, 70, 100, 20);

        v = new TextField();
        v.setBounds(120, 90, 200, 20);

        w = new TextField();
        w.setBounds(120, 110, 80, 20);

        x = new TextField();
        x.setBounds(120, 130, 80, 20);

        // create button for finding sqr
        save = new Button("Save");
        save.setBounds(120, 150, 70, 30);

        // add the action listner on this button
        save.addActionListener(this);

        // create button
        view = new Button("View");
        view.setBounds(190, 150, 70, 30);

        // add the action listner on this button
        view.addActionListener(this);

        // add all the components to the frame
        add(fname);
        add(lname);
        add(email);
        add(city);
        add(phno);
        add(t);
        add(u);
        add(v);
        add(w);
        add(x);
        add(save);
        add(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String fnme = t.getText();
        String lnme = u.getText();
        String emal = v.getText();
        String cty = w.getText();
        String phn = x.getText();

        if (e.getSource() == save) {
            try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("1.txt", true)))) {
                out.println("First Name :" + fnme);
                out.println("Last Name :" + lnme);
                out.println("Email Name : " + emal);
                out.println("City : " + cty);
                out.println("Contact : " + phn);
                out.println("----------------------------------------\n");
                out.println("----------------------------------------\n");
                out.close();
                t.setText("");
                u.setText("");
                v.setText("");
                w.setText("");
                x.setText("");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CalculatorApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }else if(e.getSource() == view){
//            what to type in here????
//            needed code here!!!

                    }
    }
}
```

I just want to open the file, nothing else..

Comment: Look at `java.io` package, you will find everything you need to open a file, read/write it, etc. `BufferedReader` is a basic standard needs that lets you read `String`s.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Applets reside within a very restrictive sandbox, which prevents them from doing things that you might normally do, like basic I/O, take a look at [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) for more details

Comment: FYI: AWT is pretty dated and went out of general use in the early 2000's.  You might consider looking into Swing or JavaFX for alternatives

Comment: Now, what do you mean by "open"?  Do you mean open in an external program (like NotePad) or open the file, read it's contents and show it within your program?

Comment: okie so you mean to say that I shall make this using swing or java alternatives???<br>And ya, I want to open it in notepad or wordpad if possible..!!!<br> And I just started to learn java this much within weeks, I got the chapter of applet so I made it but some issues I created myself like this one, as I'll learn more, I'll create issues more..<br>Swing maybe after applet so I'd better start learning.Thanx for the replies..<br> And ya, I'll try Desktop.getDesktop().open(filename); command and reply u soon.<br> thanx again for the help!!!

Comment: *"..I got the chapter of applet.."*  Skip it and get on with more useful things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use the [Desktop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class to let the system open, edit, print, browse a file.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

This means an external application.

You might consider writing an HTML file, to make all a bit more stylish.

---

***After commenting of @MadProgrammer:***

For a sandboxed applet, that has extra security restrictions when run over the internet,
it might be better to let the applet open a second window and display the text. The text then need not be written to a file.

***If you want the file to be on your server*** to save the typed data, that would be a wrong thought: the applet is run in the client's browser.

Comment: Most likely won't work from within an applet context, from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) *"SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its SecurityManager.checkRead(java.lang.String) method denies read access to the file, or it denies the AWTPermission("showWindowWithoutWarningBanner") permission, or the calling thread is not allowed to create a subprocess"*

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad "+file);` Replace 'notepad' with the program you want to use

Comment: @MadProgrammer the fact that a file is written misled me to conclude it was used on the same computer. But you are right. Maybe I should have mentioned: **file writing is probably protected against on the internet.**

Comment: @JoopEggen I still don't know what "open" means in this context ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think my answer was entirely too premature. Extended it a bit. Would have liked to delete it; embarassing.

Answer (score 0):

below it is my code to open an .exe in my netbeans GUI program:

```
 private void clockActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
      try { 
            // file path to  open
            File u = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Desktop Countdown Timer\\DesktopCountdownTimer.exe"); 

            Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop(); 
            d.open(u); 
        } catch (IOException eevt) { 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, eevt.getMessage()); 
        } 
    }
```